# Multiple values using the N prefix

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I need to put multiple values in the @RefValue parameter to speed up the result:

I tried :
`@RefValue = N'204' --205 '`  
however, it only returned the value of the register 204.

Command:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[LOG_ListTab_Key_SP]
@Tab = N'CAD_USERS',
@RefField = N'usucod',
@RefValue = N'204'

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Logic LOG_ListTab_Key_SP:

```
deallocate cp
    set @sel = @sel + ' FROM [dbo].[log_tab] with (nolock) where logtab = '+ char(39)+ @tab + char(39) + ' and logReg.value(' + char(39) 
    set @sel = @sel +'(//@' + @filter + ')[1]' + char(39) + ', ' + char(39) + @filterTip + char(39) + ') = ' + char(39) +  @RefValue  + char(39)
    set @sel = @sel + ' union all '  
    set @sel = @sel + ' Select 999999999 as logId, '+ char(39)+ @Tab + char(39) +' as logTab, '+ @cmpDat + ' as logDat, ''Actual'' as logHost, '
    set @sel = @sel + char(39)+ 'A' + char(39) +' as logOpe, * from ' + @Tab + ' with (nolock)'
    set @sel = @sel + ' where '+ @filter + ' = '+ @RefValue  
    set @sel = @sel + ' order by logId;'
    execute (@sel)
    Return
```

How can I put multiples values in @RefValue parameter?

Comment: This may depend on the way the logic in the SP is defined but if correct, then try `@RefValue = N'204,205,206,207'` and see what results you get. The SP logic may need to have the `@RefValue` equal to a string data type (e.g. `NVARCHAR()`) if it's currently `int` to handle a string of value you can then use SP logic to split out into separate values for the output. See if that works though; otherwise, [edit] your post and show us the relevant part of the SP logic with data type of input parameter and correlated SQL return logic.

Comment: You should probably be using the two values just the same as ordinary values : `N'204'` and `N'205'`. But I'm not sure about the SQL Server assignment syntax.

Comment: @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style I inserted part of the SP logic.

Comment: @ harrymc what would your suggestion be?... N'204' AND N'205' AND N'206' or N'204', N'205', N'206' with commas?

Comment: Are you trying to speed up your query or actually get more values returned per execution? If you want to add more where for filter, change the SP to use `WHERE column IN ('value1','value2'.,'..','...','value99')` and change your SQL statement that's built dynamically and executed to handle the input parameters accordingly. I'd have to have some test data and play with queries to help you optimize that though for better ideas.

Comment: Or see if you can use [`WHERE column IN ('value','value')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) with all your values in proper format and then concatenate it to the dynamic SQL as the variable value within the paranthesis to be executed as an input parameter string data type. I'm assuming you know further filtering gets the speed you are looking for but don't forget the database focus SE community over at https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style i want more values returned per execution.

Comment: @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style In the SP logic, where do I put the WHERE IN?

Comment: You are going to have to test this for the syntax with the dynamic as I don't have time to test it for the day but I believe you will replace `' where '+ @filter + ' = '+ @RefValue ` with `' where '+ @filter + ' IN ('+ @RefValue +')'` but you will want to test and confirm where to concatenate and put the `+` and single quotes to be exact. It should just be a trivial matter so backup your proc logic to a file before you start playing with it or create a test SP with a different name until confirmed

Comment: @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style in the second line of the SP logic, there is also ' `@RefValue`, in this second line I don't need to change anything?

Comment: The `char(39)` makes it harder for me since I do not have the data nor the SQL up at the moment to test dynamic SQL but see https://pastebin.com/1DP8YU0i for how I'd write it without the `char(39)` and just using additional single quotes to escape single quotes.  I have not been able to test or validate any of this, so please backup your SP beforehand or play with this in a test SP. If you need the `char(39)` rather than escaped single quotes, that'll take me longer to figure out but it is just trivial so I gave you what is easiest for me since I'm in a time crunch at the moment. Good luck!

Comment: New comment with updated link, see above now actually @Clamarc

Comment: @Vomit IT, ok i'm verify your code, thanks.

Comment: @Clamarc Sure, no problem, it's been a while since I left that comment. Let me know if it helped you or not/